# JFXTreeTableView not show all columns

Tags: javafx, jscrollpane, jfoenix

I was using JavaFX TreeTableView , both vertical & horizontal scroll bars works and I can see all the table's columns when scrolling horizontally.

now I update same table using JFXTreeTableView of JFoenix...I can see some of the columns (fit the size of the table) ,and the rest not shows and the horizontal scroll bar is limited in movement & when I drag to resize the frame, the table size remain same size ...
Any idea how to solve this ?

P.S: not using Scene builder to make the table, just hard coding it ...and the table sits on a JavaFX ScrollPane.`

```
all columns made as this column,to make short code here


@FXML
protected JFXTreeTableView<Page> table;
@FXML
protected JFXTreeTableColumn<Page,String> location;

private TreeItem<Page> root;
private ObservableList<Page> observList;

@FXML
private void someMethod(ActionEvent event){
location=new JFXTreeTableColumn<> ("Location");
table=new JFXTreeTableView<> ();

observList=FXCollections.observableArrayList ();
observList.add (new Page (1,"1","1-
 A","Math","23/4/2017","8:30","room 5"));

root=new RecursiveTreeItem<Page> 
(observList,RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);

location.setCellValueFactory (new 
Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Page, 
String>, ObservableValue<String>> () {
@Override
public ObservableValue<String> 
 call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Page, String> 
param) {
    return param.getValue ().getValue ().getCLASSESLOCATION ();
}
});
location.setCellFactory (TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn 
());

location.setOnEditCommit (new 
EventHandler<TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent<Page, 
String>> () {
@Override
public void handle(TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent<Page, 
 String> event) {
    TreeItem<Page> prinClassTableTimeEdited= 
table.getTreeItem (event.getTreeTablePosition ().getRow ());
    prinClassTableTimeEdited.getValue ().setCLASSESLOCATION 
(event.getNewValue ());
}
});

table.setRoot (root);
table.setShowRoot (false);

table.getColumns ().addAll 
(grade,class,prinClassesTableDate,time,location);

scrollPanel.setContent (table);

}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @Bill Tsagas ..hi, I added the code...a one column of many to save space.  On normal TreeTableView all goes well....on JFXTreeTableView...the horizontal scroll gets limited.